# Is there a way to keep a SwiftUI text label from slightly moving while displaying a timer?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a simple `HStack` containing 2 `Text` structs displaying a timer. It keeps changing position slightly while the timer value changes. Is there a way to avoid this behavior.

```
struct DurationLabel: View {
    let majorDuration: String // the hours/minutes part "00:00"
    let minorDuration: String // the seconds part "00"

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Text(majorDuration + minorDuration)
                .font(.system(size: 90))
            Text(minorDuration)
                .font(.body)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Demo GIF]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For displays like this I prefer to use a font with monospaced digits. You can use them in your Text like so:

```
Text("your Text here").font(Font.largeTitle.monospacedDigit())
```

Comment: Cleanest solution! Thx
For iOS 17

Answer (score 7):

I've done this a number of times for audio players, etc... If you want to keep the same font, you can do something like:

```swift
ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
  Text("00:00").opacity(0.0)
  Text("MM:SS") // Put your actual numbers in here with the same formatting.
}
```

The `ZStack` will size itself based on the largest subview, and `0` is the widest digit in basically any font.

With `.center` alignment this will keep surrounding views from shifting around each second. With `.leading`, you keep the label itself from shifting too much.

This technique works for any type of content that may change size.  Just load up a "dummy" view with the largest possible version and hide it.  Then keep your real content in the visible view.  Then you can avoid hardcoding a frame size, etc...

Comment: Good solution! Perfect when I don't want to use monospaced text!

Comment: I'm not sure how this solution works. Because in my case the second Text is keep moving.

Comment: @carlo97 Depending on your application, you may want something like `ZStack(alignment: .leading)`, which keeps the bulk of the text stable as the seconds change rapidly.

Comment: Because I am using a custom font text with is "Oswald-Medium" it can be that this text is not mono-digit?

Comment: Nice simple solution that works great if you don't want to rely on monospaced fonts.